# HowToGraphQL - Chapter 6 Authentication - Why is postedBy() invoked?

Tags: authentication, graphql, apollo-server

I hope I can get clarity when asking this question since GraphQL is a fairly obscure concept and there aren't that many answers online.

In the tutorial (https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/6-authentication/) in the #Resolving relations section near the middle of the page there's this code:

```
function postedBy(parent, args, context) {
  return context.prisma.link.findUnique({ where: { id: parent.id } }).postedBy()
}
```

Why is postedBy() called at the end?

Super confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is **not strictly related to auth** [reasons] ... creating `post` mutation will work without that. But:

- `post` mutation creates an [`Link`] entry with a relation (to `User` in prisma schema meaning [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations) );
- `postedBy` is a virtual field - *'Relation fields define connections between models at the Prisma level and **do not exist in the database**. '*;
- `post` mutation returns a `Post` type - then 'asked' return object can contain `postedBy` field (and its `User` object/type subfield[-s]);
- when `postedBy` field is queried (as part of mutation result tree), it (related `User` object/type - graphql context) must be resolved using `function postedBy(parent, args, context)`;

In resolver body we're using/working with "Prisma client" - ORM lib, then:

```
context.prisma.link.findUnique({ where: { id: parent.id } }).postedBy()
```

- `context.prisma` is/gives an access to client from graphql server context;
- `context.prisma.link` is/gives an access to links API:

> From [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model): Models:
>
> - Represent the **entities** of your application domain;
> - Map to the **tables in your database**
> - Form the foundation of the **queries** available in the generated Prisma Client API

- `context.prisma.link.findUnique({ where: { id: parent.id } })` - queries for DB link entity - returns a `Link` 'instance' (prisma context);
- `context.prisma.link.findUnique({ where: { id: parent.id } }).postedBy()` - still prisma client API context (not graphql - resolver), **not *'calling itself'*** ;

See docs: [Prisma client fluent api](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#fluent-api)

- prisma's `.postedBy()` gets a connection to `User` (prisma) 'instance', returned as/resolved to `User` (graphql) object/type (with `id` read from DB table);
- `postedBy { id }` requested (in query) could be satisfied ... but `sendBy` `User` part of `post` mutation result (Link.postedBy) can be asked to contain `links` (and subfields) - `function links(parent, args, context) {` is for resolving that relation/connection;
- each of returned links can be queried for `postedBy` user fields ...

... it's a graph/tree, completely resolvable now (nodes, DB entries and relations, virtuals)

Comment: thank you. I read up on the Fluent api and now it makes sense.